# Limit for Device Group Messaging (FCM)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

As per docs, it is stated that -
*"The maximum number of members allowed for a notification key is 20."*

What are 'members' here? Are they the registration tokens?

[Device group messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/device-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a notification key is associated with a list of registration tokens, as you can see in the same reference you linked:

> Create the notification_key, which identifies the device group by mapping a particular group (typically a user) to **all of the group's associated registration tokens**. You can create notification keys on the app server or on Android client apps

Therefore the members are devices, which are identified by registration tokens.

Comment: Can you check out a similar post of mine, please. Maybe you could share some insight if you have time and the experience
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61938591/firebase-one-signal-push-notifications-guidance

Comment: Does this mean we can't add more than 20 members in one group?

Answer (score 0):

I asked myself the same question.

As I couldn't find any answer I made a Puppeteer script.

By members, it means 20 active registration_ids. After running 20 times my script, it appeared that even if the documentation states `The maximum number of members allowed for a notification key is 20`, the API limits to 100.

Error is `Total registrations will exceed the max allowed limit of 100`

Comment: Does this mean we can't add more than 20 members in one group?